# Compiler Warning: Initialization incompatible pointer type

Tags: c

I am new to C, and I can't figure it out, why I am getting initialization incompatible poniter type warning.The relevant parts of the code are:

```
struct a {
  int address;
  B * apples[8];
} A;

struct b {
  int color;
} B;
```

I have an array of A's called a_list. What I am currently doing is:

```
B *b_list = a_list[i].apples;   // i being an index in for loop
b_list[6].color = 0;
```

The above works correctly, but throws the warning:

```
  Initialization from incompatible pointer type.
```

In order to fix it, my reasoning is that I should be doing

```
B ** b_list = a_list[i].apples;  // as it is pointer to pointer. 
So now b_list basically points to a pointer which points to an array of 6, yea?
So: (*b_list)[6].color          // However this causes segmentation fault.
```

It was also working correctly when the struct A had B apples[8], rather than B* apples[8]. However, using this solution does not maintain the changes made in functions outside of where they were made.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It was also working correctly when the struct A had B apples[8],
>   rather than B* apples[8]. However, using this solution does not
>   maintain the changes made in functions outside of where they were
>   made.

Pass a pointer to the object to such functions and your changes will persist outside of them. The reason they didn't is because you were passing the object by value.

Answer (score 1):

`A` and `B` are not types, but instances of `struct a` and `struct b`. Perhaps you want to use the classic C idiom but you are missing a `typedef`:

```
typedef struct a {
    ...
} A;
```

Now `struct a` and `A` are the same thing.

In your last code snippet, `(*b_list)[6].color` should actually be `(*b_list[6]).color` or better yet `b_list[6]->color`.

Comment: Both the above causes segmentation faults. Is it because some blocks haven't been malloced?

Comment: @Catie: Have you allocated each of the `B`s in the array?