# how to declare a struct that will not generate warning?

Tags: c, struct

The question seems to be a classic one, but I didn't find an answer:

I have two struct type written in C ------ struct type A and struct type B, and B use A while A use B at the same time.

In a.h:

```
#include "b.h"
struct B;
typedef struct A {
    void (*func)(struct B* b);
}A;
```

In b.h:

```
#include "a.h"
typedef struct B {
    A a;
}B;
```

though this will work, it has a consequence --- when using the function fun "func", if I pass a variable declared in the form:

```
B* someb;
```

not:

```
struct B* someb;
```

there will be a warning when compiling, saying incompatible pointer type. Is this normal? could I avoid this warning?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252780/why-should-we-typedef-a-struct-so-often-in-c

Comment: Sorry, but what I want to do i to **avoid the warning**, as I want to use "B someb;" to define variables rather than "struct B someb;" through all cases. Is that possible?

Comment: @user816109 : sure - see the answer below ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your `a.h` header file, simply remove the line `#include "b.h"`. The forward declaration `struct B;` is all you need.

That change will fix the circular include dependency, and will make any code using these headers more sane.

Then, wherever you want to make use of the `B` struct, simply include `b.h`, and use it with or without the `struct` keyword.

Some code to illustrate : the `a.h` header file :

```
/* a.h */
struct B;

typedef struct A {
    void (*func)(struct B* b);
} A;
```

The `b.h` header file :

```
/* b.h */
#include "a.h"

typedef struct B {
    A a;
} B;
```

A file that uses these header files :

```
/* some_file.c */
#include "b.h"

void fun() {
    B someb;
    someb.a.func(&someb);
}

void fun2() {
    struct B someb;
    someb.a.func(&someb);
}
```

Both `fun` and `fun2` are just fine (from the compiler point of view - `func` hasn't been initialized, so calling it will cause an issue at run time).

Comment: yeah, you are right! I miss the forward declaration. BTW, could you tell me how could I be clear of compiler's view of struct like you(i.e. these trival things about struct declaration)? what kind of material can I read?

Comment: @realjin : the compiler is happy when your code is syntactically correct. So, knowing the C syntax in detail helps a lot. While the C standard is the definitive resource, it's a bit difficult to read. But any good resource on C will teach you much already.

Answer (score 2):

Cyclic include dependencies are never a good idea.

The simplest way is to have forward declarations for the `struct` tag **and** the `typedef` in "a.h"

```
typedef struct A A;
typedef struct B B;
```

Comment: thanks, you pointed the key thing --- I missed the forward declarations.

Answer (score 0):

Function `func` as you declared it gets as input a pointer to a `struct B` object, so when calling the function you should do like this:

```
B* somePointer; //because of your typedef you can omit struct 
func(somePointer);
```

I omitted the part of allocation of memory you should also manage...

As SO question [Compiler Warning: Initialization incompatible pointer type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825903/compiler-warning-initialization-incompatible-pointer-type) shows, you should pass a pointer to the function in order to make changes visible in the object, otherwise you are just passing a copy of struct B and every change you make will only last in the functions scope.

I believe that's the reason of the warning.

Comment: Just as I mentioned in the comments below the question, my program runs well, what I want to do is to **avoid the warning**.

Comment: @user816109 `incompatible pointer type` is a typical warning when you're messing up with pointers arguments that don't match with the predefined standard. 
My guess is that the reason of this warning is because of what I pointed out, you are free to accept this suggestion or not.

Comment: sorry I made a typo --- that should be "B* someb;" and "struct B* someb;". I've corrected it just now.

Comment: @user816109 no problem!glad you found your answer

Answer (score 0):

The `struct whatever { /* ... */ };` defines a new type.
That new type name is **`struct whatever`**.

You can define another name for the type with `typedef` either in the same statement that defines the type

```
typedef struct whatever { /* ... */ } newtypename;
```

or in a different statement

```
struct whatever { /* ... */ };
typedef struct whatever newtypename;
```

You can even define a `struct` type with no name and get a new name for it

```
typedef struct { /* ... */ } newtypenameforstructwithnotag;
```